# jQuery .load() animation

Tags: jquery

I am trying to write simple page with dynamic content load. I am use a .load() function and it work. But now i want to add some animation for showing page and hiding page. For example, hiding page slide to right and showing page slideUp.

Here is my code.

```
$('.main_nav a').click(function(){
    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' .first_section';

    $('.content').load(toLoad);

    return false;
});
```

Can somebody help me or show me the right direction?

For example, we have a 2 div's (index.php .first_section and about.php .first_section), when we click on 'about.php' link:

1. start hiding animation (using .animate() function) for "index.php .first_section"
2. Load "about.php .first_section", but this div not showing
3. start opening animation (using .animate() function) for loaded ".first_section"

Answer (score 0):

Make the `.content` section `display:none` by default.  Then in your javascript:

```
$('.main_nav a').click(function(){
    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' .first_section';

    var content = $('.content');
    content.slideUp(); // hide the current content
    content.load(toLoad);
    content.slideDown(); // show the new content

    return false;
});
```

Change `slideUp()` to whatever animation you want to use to hide the element, and `slideDown()` to whatever animation you want to use to show the element.

Comment: It does make it possible to apply animation to ".first_section " sections? I mean 2 different animation for 2 different elements

Comment: maybe .addClass() and removeClass() for ".first_section "

Comment: I don't understand what `.first-section` is for, or why you're adding it to the AJAX URL.  In your current code, you are loading content using a single selector, `.content`', which could select zero or more elements.  Perhaps you could elaborate in your question and post your HTML code as well.

Comment: I still don't understand.  Include the rendered HTML code for the page where you want this functionality in your question.

Comment: http://tympanus.net/Development/PageTransitions/   if you click on 'choose transition' and then pick a 'slide' you understand what i want. But i need it with ajax page loading.